# Conversion of 12 Hour Clock to 24 Hour Clock in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion

```
    SELECT CONVERT(time ,' 00:00:12 PM')
```

Why doesn't the above Code work. What to do to make it Work.

For some reason "00:00:00 PM" to "00:59:59 PM" fails to convert into Time :(

"1:00:00 PM" gets successfully Converted.

---

Thanks in Advance. Someone please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CONVERT can be used as a CAST but with a FORMAT for dates to get this already well understood literal to be a specific format.

You however want to use PARSE to get this maybe not so well understood literal to become a datetime or time (which doesn't have a format). To tell the engine how to interprrt the literal we type USING.

Check it:

```
SELECT PARSE(' 00:00:12 PM' AS time USING 'en-US')
```

Comment: That is a SQL Server 2012 Command. Am using SQL Server 2008 R2. What do i do now??

Answer (score 2):

00:00 PM does not exist I think. It is either 12:00 AM or 12:00 PM. 00:00 only exists in the 24h format.